# How to animate animatedSprite from specific index? - andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Does anybody know how to animate sprite from specific index(in my case from current index)? I try something but without success -

```
    if (!sprite.isAnimationRunning()) {
     int index = sprite.getCurrentTileIndex();
     sprite.animate(frameDurations, index, 7, true);
    }
```

and every time I have an exception because frameDurations doesn't equal frameCount. I just want to animate the sprite from currentIndex when button is pressed. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
sprite.animate(new long[]{}, "your current index", "your last index", loop );

Use this function to animate sprite from specific index to your last index. add how many number of 
frames time to animate that from current index to last index . and loop is `boolean varible` that    signifies animate once or `repeate`.
```

Comment: I wrote this in my question, but it doesn't work just like that.. because the current index is changes every time, and when index is changed the "new long[]{}" should be different. In my case I find this long[]frameDuration with "for loop", but I'm not sure if this is the good way to do this. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This sprite  has 8 frames.Im trying to animate the 7th and 8th frame .Once that is finished i will animate from frame 0 to 6  where 100 is the duration

```
Player.sprite.animate(
                                            new long[] { 100, 100 }, 7, 8,
                                            false, new IAnimationListener() {

                                                public void onAnimationStarted(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pInitialLoopCount) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationLoopFinished(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pRemainingLoopCount,
                                                        int pInitialLoopCount) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationFrameChanged(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                        int pOldFrameIndex,
                                                        int pNewFrameIndex) {

                                                }

                                                public void onAnimationFinished(
                                                        AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
                                                    Player.sprite.animate(
                                                            new long[] { 100,
                                                                    100, 100,
                                                                    100, 100,
                                                                    100, 100 },
                                                            0, 6, true);
                                            }
                                        });
```